# How to retrieve photos back after iTunes backup upload in iPhone 7 and iOS 13?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, icloud, backup

I have an iPhone 7 and i installed a backup which belongs to a few days ago. But i had several photos important i took yesterday. But i most probably didn't back them up. Is it still possible to bring them back?

Thanks in any advance.

Comment: Do you have iCloud enabled for Photos?

Comment: Yes, it is enabled

Comment: Did you check whether the photos are still available on icloud.com?

Comment: Unfortunately, they are not available. I just checked

Comment: Unless you had these photos backed-up somewhere, locally or on a site like Dropbox, they're probably gone now.

Comment: Still no way to bring them back?

Comment: What precisely did you do to “install a backup” iOS won’t load a backup unless you have a wiped device, so how it got to the wiped state will dictate the expense and chance of success to find anything from the storage.

Answer (score 1):

You can check to see if you have any backups of your iPhone on your computer with a tool like [iBackup Extractor](https://www.wideanglesoftware.com/ibackupextractor/). You can access and browse the contents of such a backup (free) to see if your photos are there. If you want to extract more than 20 photos, though, you'll need to buy a licence.

Answer (score 0):

Unless they somehow made it to the recently deleted photos, they are probably gone.
Just make sure you don't have an iCloud backup on your phone. 
Settings > tap your name at top > iCloud > iCloud Backups.